# Errorlevel variable not changing after error..?

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

I'm trying to do a script that will run constantly in background. Its goal is to detect USB flash drives, external hard drives, or any writable device that you'd connect to your computer. Once it detected one, it'd copy a file at the root of this device. Here's my code (the echo lines are for clearer debugging):

```
@echo off
:loop
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
    for %%c in (%%b) do (
        for /F "tokens=4" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
            if %%d equ amovible (
                echo Found out that %%c is removable. Trying to echo the content...
                dir %%c >NUL
                echo Error: %errorlevel%
                if %errorlevel%==0 (
                    echo Errorlevel is 0! Copying...
                    if not exist %%c\test.txt (
                        copy .\test.txt %%c\test.txt
                        echo.
                    )
                ) else (
                    echo Errorlevel isn't 0. Looks like the drive isn't here, or is unavailable. Aborting copying...
                  echo.
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
TIMEOUT 2
goto :loop
```

And here's the problem. The condition "if %errorlevel%==0" is supposed to check if the "dir %%c >NUL" command succeeded, so if errorlevel is 0, that means there's a filesystem on the device, and it's not like an empty card reader or an empty floppy drive. The thing is when I execute my code, errorlevel is always 0, and I can't figure out why ("echo Error: %errorlevel%" tells it). So the file test.txt does copy on my USB flash drive, so this basically work, the thing is when it comes to copy the file to my floppy drive, an error box shows up, saying that I should insert a device in the reader, that's why I want to do this errorlevel check.

So if someone has a solution, please help, I'm really stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (`!ErrorLevel!`), because otherwise, you get the `ErrorLevel` present when the entire parenthesised block (loop) is parsed...

Comment: Whoaaw, thanks man! Worked like a charm!

Comment: You could of course use the classic `if not errorlevel 1 ...` which doesn't need delayed expansion.

Comment: You're welcome! What is the loop `for %%c in (%%b) do ( ... )` intended for?

Comment: +aschipfl Well the `fsutil fsinfo drives` commande lists the differents drive letters, so the `for` loop is used to check them one by one

Comment: Since `if ErrorLevel 1` means "if `ErrorLevel` is greater than or equal to `1`", the inverse statement `if not ErrorLevel 1` means "if `ErrorLevel` is less than `1`"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (`!ErrorLevel!`), because otherwise, you get the `ErrorLevel` value that is present when the entire parenthesised block (that is the nested `for` loop structure here) is parsed. Since exclamation marks are consumed by the delayed expansion feature, I would enable it only where it is actually needed, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:loop
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
    for %%c in (%%b) do (
        for /F "tokens=4" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
            if "%%d"=="amovible" (
                echo Found out that %%c is removable. Trying to echo the content...
                dir "%%~c" > nul
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                echo Error: !ErrorLevel!
                if !ErrorLevel! equ 0 (
                    endlocal
                    echo ErrorLevel is 0! Copying...
                    if not exist "%%~c\test.txt" (
                        copy ".\test.txt" "%%~c\test.txt"
                        echo/
                    )
                ) else (
                    endlocal
                    echo ErrorLevel isn't 0. Looks like the drive isn't here, or is unavailable. Aborting copying...
                    echo/
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
timeout 2
goto :loop
endlocal
```

Alternatively, since `dir` does never set `ErrorLevel` to a negative value, you could also use the [`if not errorlevel 1` syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), meaning "if not `ErrorLevel` is greater than or equal to `1`", and therefore "if `ErrorLevel` is less than `1`" (apparently you cannot echo the actual `ErrorLevel` value then):

```cmd
                ...
                dir "%%~c" > nul
                if not ErrorLevel 1 (
                    echo ErrorLevel is 0! Copying...
                    if not exist "%%~c\test.txt" (
                        copy ".\test.txt" "%%~c\test.txt"
                        echo/
                    )
                ) else (
                    echo ErrorLevel isn't 0. Looks like the drive isn't here, or is unavailable. Aborting copying...
                    echo/
                )
                ...
```

Another method is to use the [conditional execution operators `&&` and/or `||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html), which lets the following command or block execute only in case the preceding command returns an exit code of zero (most of the time, and also for the `dir` command here, the exit code is the same value as `ErrorLevel`):

```cmd
                ...
                dir "%%~c" > nul && (
                    echo ErrorLevel is 0! Copying...
                    if not exist "%%~c\test.txt" (
                        copy ".\test.txt" "%%~c\test.txt"
                        echo/
                    )
                ) || (
                    echo ErrorLevel isn't 0. Looks like the drive isn't here, or is unavailable. Aborting copying...
                    echo/
                )
                ...
```

Comment: +1 for the very good answer. I don't understand why people are using `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0` or within a command block `if !ERRORLEVEL! == 0` instead of `if not errorlevel 1` to test for exit code of previous executed command/application being 0 (or negative) as the method not expanding the environment variable works since MS-DOS and for which Microsoft even wrote a support article many, many years ago, see [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Comment: Thank you, @Mofi! Yes, I totally agree, I think the `if ErrorLevel` syntax existed even before the pseudo-variable `%ErrorLevel%` has been introduced; anyway, people seem to be still confused by that syntax; I believe they run into trouble by misinterpreting `if ErrorLevel 1` as "if `ErrorLevel` equals `1`" rather than "if `ErrorLevel` is greater than or equal to `1`", so they prefer the more obvious variants `if %ErrorLevel% equ 1`, etc...

Comment: +aschipfl Ooooh, it's "greater than or equal"?? I didn't know that! I thought it was just "is equal to", thanks for the tip man ^^!

Comment: Hello again. I have an other problem, haha ^^'. And it's useless to create an other question here since it's related to this script. It's surely a really dumb thing that I don't know, but here: those lines of code above have to be written in a file by a batch script. But. When I try to echo them, for exemple `echo for %%c in (%%b) do ( > usb.bat`, the first `%` sign is not there, so the created script doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is actually worth a new question, because it is not that trivial; basically you will need to escape several characters by preceding with `^`, except the `%`, which needs to be doubled like `%%` to get one literal `%`...

Comment: @aschipfl Hum... So, this is kind of a weird hack, but I tried putting four % signs, like: `echo for %%%%c in (%%%%b) do ( > usb.bat`, and well, it works. There's only two % signs in the final file. So I don't know if it was the right thing to do, but hey, works now ^^'. If you have a better solution please tell haha. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: @aschipfl Oh, okay, now that I read your comment again, you were totally telling me to do this, haha sorry, my english isn't good sometimes =w=